# How to simulate user movement for an Android Activity?

Tags: android, automated-tests

I have to test my android phone when it is in state of move, but phone is still in moment of testing. Is there a way (or application) to simulate activity move?

Something like fake GPS, just it is fake movement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use new emulator to simulate GPS readings. Click three dots on emulator toolbar, click location then you can add locations you want to simulate, or provide a GPX/KML file that simulation will follow

Answer (score 4):

Yeah definitely the one below works perfectly :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=en

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

As [@xklakoux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/944734/xklakoux) said, the Android emulator enables you to simulate measurements from onboard devices such as the *GPS*, *Accelerometer*, *Gyroscope* etc.

If you'd like to programmatically mock locations within your application during tests, you can add the `MOCK_LOCATION` permission to your staging environment's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />`

Then define a simulated location service, which may be executed as a threaded task, as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import java.util.Random;

/** A class that mocks Location data in Android. */
public final class MockLocationProvider implements Runnable {

/* Member Variables. */
private final String  mProviderName;
private final Context mContext;
private final long    mBeaconPeriod;
private       double  mLatitude;
private       double  mLongitude;
private       double  mAltitude;
private       float   mAccuracy;
private       boolean mRunning;

/** Constructor. */
public MockLocationProvider(final String pProviderName, final Context pContext, final long pBeaconPeriod) {
    // Initialize Member Variables.
    this.mProviderName = pProviderName;
    this.mContext      = pContext;
    this.mBeaconPeriod = pBeaconPeriod;
    this.mLatitude     = 0.0;
    this.mLongitude    = 0.0;
    this.mAltitude     = 0.0;
    this.mAccuracy     = 0.0f;
    this.mRunning      = false;
}

/** Sets up the Mock Location Provider. */
public final void open() {
    // Fetch the LocationManager.
    final LocationManager lLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Register ourself as a TestProdier.
    lLocationManager.addTestProvider(this.getProviderName(), false, false, false, false, false, true, true, 0, 5);
    // Enable the transmission of mock locations.
    lLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(this.getProviderName(), true);
    // Assert that we're running.
    this.mRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // Are we still running?
    if(this.isRunning()) {
        // Publish the current location.
        this.publishLocation(this.getLatitude(), this.getLongitude(), this.getAlitude(), this.getAccuracy());
        // Sleep for the BeaconPeriod.
        try { Thread.sleep(this.getBeaconPeriod()); } catch (final InterruptedException pInterruptedException) { pInterruptedException.printStackTrace(); }
        // Run again.
        this.run();
    }
}

// Update the local parameters. (With a random accuracy between 10 and 15 meters.)
public final void setLocation(final double pLatitude, final double pLongitude, final double pAltitude) throws Exception {
    // Allocate a random Accuracy, in meters. (Range: 5m <= n < 15m).
    final float lAccuracy = (10.0f * (new Random()).nextFloat()) + 5.0f;
    // Update the member variables.
    this.setLocation(pLatitude, pLongitude, pAltitude, lAccuracy);
}

// Update the local parameters.
public final void setLocation(final double pLatitude, final double pLongitude, final double pAltitude, final float pAccuracy) throws Exception {
    // Update the member variables.
    this.mLatitude  = pLatitude;
    this.mLongitude = pLongitude;
    this.mAltitude  = pAltitude;
    this.mAccuracy  = pAccuracy;
    // Wait a period.
    Thread.sleep(this.getBeaconPeriod());
}

/** Publishes a mock location to the device. */
public final void publishLocation(final double pLatitude, final double pLongitude, final double pAltitude, final float pAccuracyMeters) {
    // Fetch the LocationManager.
    final LocationManager lLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Allocate a Location.
    final Location lLocation = new Location(this.getProviderName());
    // Configure the Location Metrics.
    lLocation.setLatitude(pLatitude);
    lLocation.setLongitude(pLongitude);
    lLocation.setAltitude(pAltitude);
    lLocation.setAccuracy(pAccuracyMeters);
    lLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());
    // Use the CurrentTimeMillis as the Location.
    lLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Mock the location.
    lLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(this.getProviderName(), lLocation);
}

/** Closes the down the Mock Provider. */
public final void close() throws Exception {
    // Stop running.
    this.setRunning(false);
    // Wait for the last beacon.
    Thread.sleep(this.getBeaconPeriod());
    // Fetch the LocationManager.
    final LocationManager lLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Remove ourself as the Test Provider.
    lLocationManager.removeTestProvider(this.getProviderName());
}



private final String getProviderName() {
    return this.mProviderName;
}

private final Context getContext() {
    return this.mContext;
}

private final long getBeaconPeriod() {
    return this.mBeaconPeriod;
}

public final double getLongitude() {
    return this.mLongitude;
}

public final double getLatitude() {
    return this.mLatitude;
}

public final double getAlitude() {
    return this.mAltitude;
}

public final float getAccuracy() {
    return this.mAccuracy;
}

private final void setRunning(final boolean pIsRunning) {
    this.mRunning = pIsRunning;
}

public final boolean isRunning() {
    return this.mRunning;
}

}
```

This may then be instantiated using:

`new MockLocationProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mContext, 200L)`